# How Can I Delete Xampp Permanently on Mac Os?

Tags: php, mysql, macos, phpmyadmin, xampp

I used Xampp and deleted it.
Then, I tried to use Mamp. There is an error that I don't understand. 
Mamp is working perfect as webserver. But if I want to use phpmyadmin, it doesn't work.

For example, I insert something to database. It isn't showing in phpmyadmin.
It is saving to old Xampp database although I deleted Xampp. How does it happen?

How Can I delete Xampp permanently(with mysql) on Mac OS?

Answer (score 58):

### XAMPP 5.x:

You can find `uninstall.app` in `/Applications/XAMPP`.

[image: uninstall.app]

After running this program, then you can use this command to delete all XAMPP cache files: `sudo rm -rf /Applications/XAMPP`

### XAMPP 7.x:

- Open Mac OS *Finder* and go to `/Applications` folder. You should find an XAMPP icon there (eg. XAMPP.app), right-click it and choose 'Move to Trash'.
- In addition to this, you might want to delete the ~/.bitnami folder within your home directory.

Comment: Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Macs need to work on a consistent way to uninstall applications. Drag to trash to delete...sure...but some apps leave fragments of themselves in places like /Application Support of /Extensions. If deleting ".app" I think the OS should then ask "Would you like uninstall this app?" and then just do so.

Answer (score 8):

the newer version of XAMPP include uninstaller apps, you can find it inside XAMPP folder in Application directory. But they leave empty XAMPP folder.

Comment: The XAMPP folder that is left behind may not be empty: It contains all your MySQL databases and the htdocs directory. This is really useful since that's the stuff you probably want to keep after you uninstall XAMPP.

Answer (score 8):

**To Delete XAMPP**

Step 1:

*Go to your Application folder and delete it.*

Step 2:

*Open your terminal and type: sudo rm -rf ~/.bitnami*

Answer (score 7):

```
To uninstall XAMPP-VM, follow these steps:

    Delete the XAMPP-VM icon from the Applications folder.
    Remove all XAMPP-VM data by deleting the ~/.bitnami folder within your home directory on the OS X host.
```

https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_stackman.html

Comment: Is there some way to preserve databases and files by just re-initializing xampp?

Comment: backup is the king

Comment: The king has been slain along with his heir.

Answer (score 2):

I think that just put the application (in your Applications folder) is enough. But you can try to search some XAMPP garbages.

Open your terminal, sudo and search for something containing XAMPP:

```
sudo -s
[ Type your password ]
find / | grep -i xampp
```

It can take a time if you do not have a fast hdd.
This will display all files/folder containing XAMPP in their name.

Comment: Thank for reply. Xampp files were found only .Trash folder.

Comment: This was perfect for helping me find the local mounted machine and delete the files!

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Spotlight and search for XAMPP,

> To open Spotlight, click the magnifying glass icon in the upper-right
>   corner of the menu bar, or press Command-Space from any app.

2. Should be displayed some folders. Check for XAMPP (in upper cases) folder and open it.
3. XAMPP folder  should contain an uninstall programm, tap on it and follow the instructions.
4. For a complete remove Go to Macintosh HD and delete the folder /Aplications/XAMPP (Be careful with you application files).

I did it right now and it works.

Answer (score 1):

it's easy pro,
Open the application folder.
Click on the XAMPP icon and hold it.
Drag the icon to Trash.
Clean Trash (to do it just hold Ctrl and click on “Empty Trash”).

Answer (score 1):

run this command on the terminal:
rm -fr ~/.bitnami/