# How to uninstall Xampp-VM 7.2 completely in Mac?

Tags: php, macos, xampp

Actually when i tried to uninstall it , and reinstall it , it restore automatically all old files , without creating new ones .

I had the latest Xampp 7.2.10 , i removed it from my mac to reinstall new one  , the Xampp that i removed i had changed mistakenly it's etc folder files , however when i reinstalled it i got same old etc folder which are corrupted  , and i got same everything as the old Xampp which i already deleted.

This problem i tried to solved it the whole day but i got same problem over and over again .

The [old way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25286958/how-can-i-delete-xampp-permanently-on-mac-os) of deinstalling it doesn't seem to work with 7.2.

Answer (score 2):

The XAMPP-VM virtual machine files and logs are stored within your home directory on the OS X host, in the ~/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/vm (invisible folder).
Just delete the .bitnami folder and re-lunch XAMPP to have a clean installation of Lampp volume.